# Mixed mode on but still getting not trusted connection error

Tags: sql-server, ado.net, asp-classic

I'm trying to make a connection a sql 2000 db. Mixed mode is switched on and i can connect via query analyser to all users needed, however when i try and make a connection use ado it gives me this error:

> Login failed for user 'username'.
>   Reason: Not associated with a trusted
>   SQL Server connection.

I have no idea why this is happening and its happening on more than one machine which makes me suspect its the dbserver that is the issue. All sources on the web suggest its because i don't have mixed mode on but it definately is.

```
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=server;Database=schotime1;User Id=sa; Password=mypass;"
```

Anyone seen this or has an idea what i'm doing wrong.
Cheers.

Comment: Can you include a snippet of the code your using to establish the connection?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your app is trying to use Windows Authentication to connect. Does your connection string contain "Integrated Security=True"?

Comment: It does not contain that. Will update to show connection string.